# How does const affect a function when used in the return type

Tags: c++, constants, auto

How does `const` affect `function1` and makes it any different from `function2`?

```
const int function1(const int &a) 
{
    return a+1;
}

int function2(const int &a)
{
    return a+1;
}
```

I would expect the variable returned to be `const int` instead of `int`, but putting together a script it doesn't seem to be the case since I can modify both variables returned from `function1` and `function2` and they don't seem to have any apparent difference. The following code works with no problem for instance:

```
int main () {
    int a = 1;
    auto b = function1(a);
    auto c = function2(a);
    ++b;
    ++c;
}
```

Comment: If the return type is not a pointer or a reference, the `const` makes no difference.

Comment: @Peter, in the case of the pointer you are referring to the `const` of the pointed-to object which makes a difference, not of the pointer itself, right?

Comment: @EnricoMariaDeAngelis indeed it does cover the same material. If I can get the answers over this example however I still believe it helps having the question oriented to a specific example for clarity. If the community decides otherwise I will understand it too.

Comment: @EnricoMariaDeAngelis this question is about builtin type

Answer (score 1):

According to [cppreference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/value_category#prvalue):

> A non-class non-array prvalue cannot be cv-qualified. (Note: a function call or cast expression may result in a prvalue of non-class cv-qualified type, but the cv-qualifier is immediately stripped out.)

The results returned from the functions end up as temporaries, specifically prvalues in this case. Since `int` is a primitive type, it cannot be `const` as a prvalue and thus loses its const-ness.

If we had a reference or a pointer to the `int`, we would not have a prvalue, so the `const` would be retained.